# In a one-way fixed effect model, why do we say that the demeaned variable has reduced variation?

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects

Suppose $X_{it}^*$ is the demeaned version of $X_{it}$, i.e.,
$$X_{it}^* = X_{it}- \bar{X}_i$$

In Hansen's econometrics textbook, he says the demeaned variable has reduced variation relative to the original observations, what is the precise meaning for this?

Indeed, can we prove the following inequality:
$$ Var[X_{it}^*] \leq Var[X_{it}].$$

Comment: It’s about panel data. The within-group variability is the same. It’s the between-group variability that is eliminated by the within transformation.

Comment: Average of yit minus y double bar squared versus the average of yit minus y_i bar squared.

Answer (score 3):

I have this derivation typed up as part of a PowerPoint slide. Forgive my laziness, but I'm going to just post an image of that slide.
[image]